# How to verify token signature in Nimbus JOSE + JWT

Tags: java, oauth, jwt

I have tokens going back and forth from server to client on each request for resource using [Nimbus JOSE + JWT](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-rsa-signature)

Code for creating JWT token:

```
public class TokenProvider {

    String token = "";

    public String getToken(String email) {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGenerator.initialize(1024);

            KeyPair kp = keyGenerator.genKeyPair();
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();

            System.out.println("publicKey: " + publicKey);
            System.out.println("privateKey: " + privateKey.toString());

            JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(privateKey);

            JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
            claimsSet.setSubject("RTH");
            claimsSet.setCustomClaim("email", email);
            claimsSet.setCustomClaim("role", "USER");
            claimsSet.setIssuer("https://rth.com");
            claimsSet.setExpirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000));

            SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256), claimsSet);

            signedJWT.sign(signer);
            token = signedJWT.serialize();
            TokenSaverAndValidatorDAO tokenSaver = new TokenSaverAndValidatorDAO();
            tokenSaver.saveTokenToDB(email, token);

            signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);

            JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(publicKey);
            System.out.println("verifier: " + verifier);
            System.out.println("verify method: " + signedJWT.verify(verifier));
            assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));
            assertEquals("RTH", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
            assertEquals("https://rth.com", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer());
            assertTrue(new Date().before(signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()));
        } catch (JOSEException | ParseException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TokenProvider.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

So far its working fine but the problem is how do I verify the token signature received back from client?

From the [API](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-rsa-signature), there is only one method which looks like it is for verification but its accepting only public Key (`RSAPublicKey`) as parameter rather than token.

Anyone worked on JWT using this library please help. Thank you

Answer (score 22):

There is [sample code](https://github.com/gesellix/Nimbus-JOSE-JWT/blob/master/src/test/java/example/JWSExample.java) to do this, but you have all the code in place to do this in your question.

For a shared key:

```
JWSVerifier verifier = new MACVerifier(sharedKey.getBytes());
```

If you're using an RSA keypair (as in your example), you need only supply the public key:

```
JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier((RSAPublicKey) publicKey);
```

Then ask it to verify the signature, noting that it will throw an exception if it's invalid:

```
boolean verifiedSignature = false;

    try {
      JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier((RSAPublicKey) publicKey);
      verifiedSignature = signedJWT.verify(verifier);
    }
    catch (JOSEException e) {
      System.err.println("Couldn't verify signature: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

A complete method to do check token signature might look like this:

```
public static boolean isSignatureValid(String token) {
    // Parse the JWS and verify its RSA signature
    SignedJWT signedJWT;
    try {
        signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);
        JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier((RSAPublicKey) publicKey);
        return signedJWT.verify(verifier);
    } catch (ParseException | JOSEException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```